# Анимация по нажатию на кнопку + работа с классами jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, анимация

Есть код -    https://jsfiddle.net/t8bqve2e/3/

```
<div class="cards">
        <h2 class="cards__title">Universal Life World — это</h2>
        <ul class="cards__box">
            <li class="card card1">
                <p class="card__number">20</p>
                <p class="card__descr">курортов в&nbsp;разных частях мира</p>
                <span class="card__next"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="card card2">
                <p class="card__number">50</p>
                <p class="card__descr">офисов по&nbsp;всей России</p>
                <span class="card__next"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="card card3">
                <p class="card__number">0</p>
                <p class="card__descr">довольных отдыхающих</p>
                <span class="card__next"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cards__box {
  position: relative; }

.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff512f, #f09819);
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 40px 80px 0 rgba(5, 28, 70, 0.1); }
  .card:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease; }
  .card__next {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(../app/img/icn-arrow-next.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat; }
    .card__next:hover {
      cursor: pointer; }
  .card__descr {
    width: 206px;
    font-family: 'Conv_SFUIDisplay-Regular';
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 26px; }
  .card__number {
    font-family: 'Conv_SFUIDisplay-Bold';
    font-size: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 20px; }

.card1 {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 30px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; }

.card2 {
  z-index: -2;
  transform: scale(0.9) translate(0px, 60px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; }

.card3 {
  z-index: -3;
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(0px, 90px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; }
```

**Анимация**

```css
.active {
    animation-name: background;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
@keyframes background {
    0%{
        transform: translate(0px, 0px)
            perspective(100px);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translate(0px, 250px)
            perspective(100px)
            scale(0.95);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translate(0px, 50px)
            perspective(100px)
            scale(0.9);
        z-index: -4;
    }
}
```

*Необходимо:* по клику на кнопку card__next карточка перемещалась на задний план, а следующая выдвигалась на передний.

В примере цикл for почему-то не работает. Он отвечает за позиционирование и размер последующих карточек.

*Вопрос:* Как это реализовать?

Comment: Выложите через фрагмент кода

Comment: @Алексей дайте код css

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan он по ссылке

Comment: @Alex78191 если внимательным будете то увидите что там не `css` а `scss`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan выложил CSS

Comment: html/css/js код можно оформлять фрагментом (так же как на jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".card__next").click(function () {
            var need = this;
            var nexts =  $('.card__next');
                for (var i = 0; i <= nexts.length -1; i++) {
                if (nexts[i] == need) {
                $(nexts[i]).parent().toggleClass('active');
            }
        }
     });
});
```

Как-то так

Вот ссылка https://jsfiddle.net/ksjoL3vk/1/